Build index match in excel with dynamic sheet
I'm trying to build an INDEX MATCH combo with dynamic sheet input and 3 variables for matching.
I leveraged this article to get an understanding on how to do it and I opted to go for the non-array version (or more like index native array I guess)
I ended up with the below cell-function, currently only incorporating 2 variables.
PROBLEM: This currently returns a Value Not Available Error. I've double checked the input multiple times and cannot seem to find the issue with the formula.
Current formula for clarity:
=INDEX(
INDIRECT(D2&"!J2:J20000");
MATCH(1;
(B1=INDIRECT(D2&"!E2:E20000"))*(B3=INDIRECT(D2&"!G2:G20000"));
0))



Have you evaluated the bits separately? do they work correctly? ie return the required info to the index() and match()?

The formula is correct (works on my end). Check cells B1 and B3 (D2 would show a #REF! error) for leading or trailing spaces. Do the same in columns E and G of sheet 2010 at least in the row where you think the J value should have been returned. Note also that you are not checking for Property type so the (top-most) match could be above the expected one, e.g., a cell (in column J) with an #N/A error. Share what you have discovered.

In case of Excel-2016 you need to entry the formula as array literal. Means, Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after putting the formula in cell. So, when you put the formula as array entry it will add {...} curly bracket before and after the formula. The formula will look like
{=INDEX( INDIRECT(D2&"!J2:J20000"); MATCH(1; (B1=INDIRECT(D2&"!E2:E20000"))*(B3=INDIRECT(D2&"!G2:G20000")); 0))}
